# Using linq to select an object that has a min Date after a Where condition

Tags: c#, linq

I need to initially get all products that have a Date within the startDate and endDate and since there will be multiple I need to narrow it down to just the product with the min Date afterwards.

In the end I only want to select the product with the min Date, but the Date must be between startDate and endDate.

```
var prodWithMinDate = products.Where(p => p.Date >= startDate && p.Date <= endDate);
```

If it can be done all in one linq statement that would be great, but two is fine also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    var prodWithMinDate = products.Where(p => p.Date >= startDate && p.Date <= endDate)
.OrderBy(p => p.Date)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks forgot I could just use OrderByDescending and pull the first one! Will mark as correct.

Comment: Actually wouldn't I want to order by ascending to get the min date?